# Given raw NMEA data, how do you estimate accuracy on-the-fly?

Tags: gps, nmea

I have streaming NMEA data from a GPS device to my application. One of the sentences includes HDOP. I previously calculated the circular error probable (CEP) for this unit. How can I calculate the accuracy on-the-fly using the NMEA data? Most handheld GPS units report the accuracy and I'd like to duplicate this functionality in my UI.